# How to version firebase callable cloud functions endpoints?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

What is the recommended approach for versioning [HTTPS Callable cloud functions in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to prevent breaking client functionality after deploying a new version of an endpoint?

'm seeking a solution similar to versioning REST APIs, such as incorporating the version string into the endpoint URL (e.g., /api/v1/customers/3) or utilizing custom MIME types in the Header information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no recommendation on this point in the Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation.

With Callable Cloud Functions, you can mimic the two approaches you describe in your question for API endpoint versioning.

#### "Adding the version string to the endpoint URL"

You can very well have several Callable Cloud Functions with a version number in their name, e.g.:

```
exports.doSomethingInThebackEndv1 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});

exports.doSomethingInThebackEndv2 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

#### "Including the version in custom MIME types in the Header information"

You can add the version to the object you pass to the function when calling it from your front-end. For example with the JS SDK:

```
var doSomethingInThebackEnd = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('doSomethingInThebackEnd');
doSomethingInThebackEnd({ foo: 'bar', version: 1 })
  .then((result) => {...});
```

Then in the back-end:

```
exports.doSomethingInThebackEnd = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  
  const version = data.version;

  // do different things depending on the version value

});
```

---

I admit that it is not an out-of-the-box scalable solution and that it may request a lot of manual operations in case of many different versions...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks like those two approaches are my only options then :( I had hoped for a more standardized approach by firebase, e.g. passing the version string via the context object somehow. Anyhow, will keep this question open for a bit longer to see if more answers arrive.

Comment: @B12Toaster Did you get, through other channels, other answers or suggestions of approach?

Comment: Not really, will mark your answer as accepted now, if you think the question deserves more attention, please also upvote the question, thx :)